# Facebook post to business/community page using latest PHP SDK

Tags: php, facebook, sdk

I'm trying to post stuff from my website to my facebook page (using latest facebook api).

After connecting to my app (which works fine) I have this code to post something onto my timeline.

```
$response = (new FacebookRequest(
$session, 'POST', '/me/feed', array(
'name' => 'Test 1',
'caption' => "Test 2",
'link' => 'https://www.google.com',
'message' => 'Test 3'
)));
```

This works fine, but when I change '/me/feed' to '/nameofbusinesspage/feed' it appears to login to facebook ok but then returns a lengthy error message starting . . .

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Facebook\FacebookServerException' with message 'An unexpected error has occurred. Please retry your request later.

Any ideas how I should reference the business/community page?

There's loads of threads on the old SDK - but this is v4.0 (which seems completely different).

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to use '/id-of-businesspage/feed' instead '/nameofbusinesspage/feed' ?

Comment: Thanks for responding - Yes I did try the id as well - same problem

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured it out - for anyone else . . .

Following is code after login established with facebook (referenced by the $session var) . . .

```
$pageid ="**********";
$get = (new FacebookRequest($session, 'GET', '/me/accounts'));
$accounts = $get -> execute() -> getGraphObject() -> asArray();
// get data object
$data = $accounts["data"];
// get access_token from account with matching id
foreach ($data as $page) { 
if ($page -> id == $pageid) { $accesstoken = $page -> access_token; } }
// post to facebook account
$post = (new FacebookRequest($session, 'POST', '/'.$pageid.'/feed', 
array('access_token' => $accesstoken, 
'name' => 'Test 1', 
'caption' => "Test 2", 
'link' => 'https://www.google.com', 
'message' => 'Test 3')));
$return = $post -> execute() -> getGraphObject() -> asArray();
```

$pageid is the (numeric) id of your facebook page (found under 'Settings').

Hope it saves someone the day I wasted on trial and error.